# iOS 9 call log/recent calls doesn't show blue number to identify which number is referenced

Tags: iphone, ios, phone.app

I work for a marketing company and we use iPhones.

Lots of contacts have more than a phone number saved in their business card as mobile, main, home, private ecc.

In iOS 9, in the recent calls log, can not see anymore the phone number coloured in blue as to show which number called (mobile, main, home, private, etc); a big issue if the contact has more than 2 numbers saved in his BC.

Missed calls show in red, but also don't specifically identify *which* phone number.

Would like to know if its just me or is something common that happen to you guys as well.

Comment: Just to give more details for the above thread. Even if its a missed call, I can see the name in red colour, but not from which phone number.

Comment: There may not be an answer, but you can submit feedback to Apple [here](http://apple.com/feedback)

Answer (score 2):

I believe I found the answer (from someone else) and would like to post it in case someone else will be interested.

--//--

It's no longer blued. It just shows the label under the name or number. 
[image]

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. I have multiple number with same `mobile` tag.